# Python to add, why immutable variable is faster?

Tags: python, performance

I am learning the concept mutable/immutable in python. I thought, for accumulation, mutable list would be faster than immutable variable, since it happens "in place". Please see my code:

```
import time


def use_immutable_variable():
    t = time.time()
    accumulator = 0
    for x in range(1000000):
        accumulator += x
    return time.time() - t


def use_mutable_array():
    t = time.time()
    accumulators = [0]
    for x in range(1000000):
        accumulators[0] += x
        #accumulators[0].__add__(x)
    return time.time() - t

times = []
for i in range(10):
    times.append(use_immutable_variable())
print("use_immutable_variable: %s" % (sum(times)/float(len(times))))

times = []
for i in range(10):
    times.append(use_mutable_array())
print("use_mutable_array     : %s" % (sum(times)/float(len(times))))
```

The result is:

```
use_immutable_variable: 0.1034714937210083
use_mutable_array     : 0.166017746925354
```

I guess this is not the right approach for accumulator in python. The point of this question here is that, I thought the mutable list approach would faster than the immutable one, as the changing of the mutable element happens "in place". But my testing shows that the immutable approach is faster. Can anyone give some explanation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be using `timeit` to time Python performance. `Time.time()` won't give you accurate results.

Comment: Forgetting the concept of mutability for a moment, why would you want your accumulator to be anything other than an integer if that's what it is? Why use a list to store something other than a list of things? Or am I misunderstanding you? PS - If you want to test in-place add, the method is `__iadd__` (presuming it's defined).

Comment: The only element of the `accumulators` array is just as "immutable" as the variable `accumulator` in the first function

Comment: In python the *object* is immutable, not the variable (that's why you can do something like `intVariable += 1`.

Comment: maybe it's slightly slower because in the second case, python must get the element a position 0 in the array before being able to add 1 to it, and then store the result back into the array, and this at every iteration...

Comment: @MorganThrapp I tried `timeit`, but the results looks odd: `[0.0008997839919702155, -0.002376045560545492, 0.0015100462336730125, -7.013525412680188e-05, -2.2238007406194527e-05, 0.0001954378727808681, -0.0008206680040832026, 0.0007257288186184319, 9.664980141943502e-05, -2.7797509257965203e-05]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As oseiskar remarks in the comment, this has little to do with mutability.  But the difference is easily shown by disassembling the relevant code:

```
import dis

lst = [0]
def incr_in_list():
    lst[0] += 1

n = 0
def incr():
    n += 1

dis.dis(incr_in_list)
3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (lst)
            3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            6 DUP_TOP_TWO
            7 BINARY_SUBSCR
            8 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            11 INPLACE_ADD
            12 ROT_THREE
            13 STORE_SUBSCR
            14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            17 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis(incr)
8           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
            3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
            6 INPLACE_ADD
            7 STORE_FAST               0 (n)
            10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            13 RETURN_VALUE
```

A lot less work for `+=` (no need to access the variable in the list) and calls to `LOAD_FAST` and `STORE_FAST` instead of pulling the value off the list, incrementing it (`INPLACE_ADD` in both cases) and storing it back.

Answer (score 2):

If you were appending items to an array, it would make sense to use a list rather than a tuple, but that's not what you're doing here.  Your "mutable" solution just adds an extra intermediate step before accessing an integer value, which itself is an immutable object.

Comment: Thank you very much, I also added prints to check the ID of the list, and the ID of its first element. 
`accumulators[0] += x
        print("acc    id: %s" % str(id(accumulators)))
        print("acc[0] id: %s" % str(id(accumulators[0])))`
The prints are:
`acc    id: 28510488
acc[0] id: 497506016
acc    id: 28510488
acc[0] id: 497506032`